# Homeomorphism between an open interval and an infinite interval in $R$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that:

1. (0,1) is homeomorphic to (0,$\infty$)
2. (0,1) is homeomorphic to $R$
3. (-1,1) is homeomorphic to $R$

How can I define the functions to show the above? Is there any general method to define the function like we have for any two bounded open intervals i.e.  $f:(a, b) \rightarrow(c ,d)$ by $f(x)=\alpha x+\beta$ such that $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$ ?

Also I want to know about in general what type of intervals are homeomorphic to what type of intervals in $R$, for all possible intervals in $R$, like I want to know studying the properties of which intervals is sufficient to know about the others. I googled it but I did not get complete characterization of all possible homeomorphic intervals.

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

A function like $\tan(x)$ maps $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ bijectively and continuously onto $\Bbb R$. So use a version of that to go from a *bounded* open interval to $\Bbb R$.

A function like $\frac1x$ similarly maps $(0,1)$ to $(1,\infty)$ so you can use that to go from a bounded open interval to a one-sided unbounded open segment.

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous strictly increasing function defined on an open interval is an homeomorphism onto its image.

I am pretty sure for example that you know an example of a strictly increasing function from ${\bf R}$ that converges to 1 at infinity and to -1 at minus infinity. This should give you an homeomorphism from ${\bf R}$ to $]-1,1[$. You could then consider its inverse.